# Backspace button on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

In my iPhone application I have UISearchBar element. Sometimes when I click backspace button it removes more than one symbol, sometimes only one. How can I set to remove symbols one by one, not by group?

I recognize the problem, it happens after only one click and happens after I start application first:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSLog(@"*******%@***********", searchText);
    if(!searchBar.text.length){        
        searchIsActive = false;        
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

in colsole I see:

"*******1***********"

"*******12***********"

And after I click backspace button on keyboard I see:
"******************"

So it means that searchBar.text.length return NO

Comment: Tap and release, don't hold the delete key.

Comment: Sounds almost like you need to untick the box "Clear when editing begins" or set this to false? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearsOnBeginEditing

Comment: I had a mistake in my question: I mean UISearchBar, not UITextFiled. UISearchBar doesn't have such property as clearsOnBeginEditing

Comment: Have you looked at `searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`?

Answer (score 0):

The backspace element is the system element . The OS handles that event this event rather than your application textfield . You can only make your textfield as a first responder to enable the keyboard for it . As you are not doing anything for display the characters on textfield you cant anything to remove it . I think the problem might be somewhere else.Or you are tapping wrongly on keyboard.